# Can not access the php file within the htdocs directory

Tags: php, xampp

I have the test.php file in this directory `C:\xampp\htdocs`. I can access the localhost by this link `http://localhost:800/xampp/` then it appears the orange XAMPP wlecome window but when I type the following URL `http://localhost:800/xampp/test.php` I getting something as `The required URL could not be found`. Why can not I access this file?

Apache ports: 800, 4433

MySQL ports: 3306

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Comment: `c:\xampp\htdocs` is your document root. that means `http://localhost:8000` points directly at c:\xampp/htdocs, and `http://localhost:8000/xampp/test.php` would mapped to `c:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you file is in `C:\xampp\htdocs` you should access it using `http://localhost:800/test.php`.

htdocs is the default root directory of apache. (Variable **DocumentRoot** in **conf/httpd.conf**)

Answer (score 0):

- 1) Inside the htdocs directory crate new folder test and add file
  test.php into this directory
- 2) Restart the server
- 3) Use
  `http://localhost/test/test.php`